# Is this a proper LL(1) Grammar?

Tags: formal-grammars, compilers, parsers, interpreters, ll-k

Please take this question with a grain of salt. I'm trying to write a very simple layout engine and wanted to formally create a grammar to parse the input. I stayed up all night researching LL(k) parsers - mostly from papers from different colleges. They tend to use the same examples and I've never been a fan of abstracting through notation, so I'm almost positive I have the syntax incorrect.

The input is very trivial:

```
header>rows>h-row>a|b

main>rows>m-row>qs|d
qs>qs-row>qa|qu

footer>rows>f-row>a|b
```

And this is the grammar definition:

```
S -> aBC
B -> op
C -> a
```

First:

```
S: [a]
B: [>, |, /]
C: [a]
```

Follow:

```
S: $
C: $
B: C | S
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a perfectly valid grammar, and it's certainly LL(1). But since it only generates three sentences, it's probably not what you are looking for.

The three sentences:

```
a < a
a | a
a / a
```

**For precision**: As written, it's not quite correct. In order to achieve what I imagine you meant by the FIRST sets, you'd actually need to he a bit more precise. Instead of using $op$, you write:

$$\begin{align}B& \to \mathbb{<}\\
B&\to\text{|}\\
B&\to\text{/}
\end{align}$$

Alternatively, you could define $op$ as the three possible operators, as above, and leave $B\to op$.

**Also**: $FOLLOW$ sets (like $FIRST$ sets) are sets of *terminals*. So $S$ and $C$ are not going to be found in any $FOLLOW$ set. $FOLLOW(B)$ is $\{a\}$.

Comment: Thanks for your response! It's encouraging to know I didn't go completely off the rails. Could you perhaps explain follow sets a bit more? I'm sure you did a great job explaining to begin with, but I'm having a bit of trouble grokking it.

Comment: $FOLLOW(N)$, where $N$ is a non-terminal, is the set of terminals which might in some valid sentence immediately follow the derivation of $N$. In other words, it is the union of the $FIRST$ sets of the part following $N$ in each right-hand side which includes $N$, plus the $FOLLOW$ sets of each non-terminal whose right-hand side might end with $N$. If the second description seems complicated, start with the first one, which is the actual meaning (as opposed to an algorithm which computes the set).